# What exactly does this JavaScript JSON "manipulation"?

Tags: javascript, json

I am not so into **JavaScript** and **JSON** and I have the following doubt working on an application.

I have this JSON document:

```
{
    "Markets": {
        "Market": {
            "market_name": "Kibuye",
            "market_description": "Kibuye Village Market",
            "localization_id": 1,
            "long": 29.371491,
            "lat": -2.17897,
            "country": "Rwanda",
            "regione": {
                "@nil": "true"
            },
            "province": {
                "@nil": "true"
            },
            "city": {
                "@nil": "true"
            },
            "district": {
                "@nil": "true"
            },
            "town": {
                "@nil": "true"
            },
            "village": {
                "@nil": "true"
            },
            "commodity": {
                "el": [{
                        "market_name": "Kibuye",
                        "commodity_name": "Rice-Asia",
                        "image_link": "Rice-Asia.jpg",
                        "commodity_details_id": 1
                    }, {
                        "market_name": "Kibuye",
                        "commodity_name": "Apple banana",
                        "image_link": "Apple_banana.jpg",
                        "commodity_details_id": 2
                    }, {
                        "market_name": "Kibuye",
                        "commodity_name": "Avocado",
                        "image_link": "Avocado.jpg",
                        "commodity_details_id": 3
                    }, {
                        "market_name": "Kibuye",
                        "commodity_name": "Red onion",
                        "image_link": "Red_onion.jpg",
                        "commodity_details_id": 4
                    }, {
                        "market_name": "Kibuye",
                        "commodity_name": "White onion",
                        "image_link": "White_onion.jpg",
                        "commodity_details_id": 5
                    }, {
                        "market_name": "Kibuye",
                        "commodity_name": "Green Beans",
                        "image_link": "Green_Beans.jpg",
                        "commodity_details_id": 6
                    }, {
                        "market_name": "Kibuye",
                        "commodity_name": "Bell pepper",
                        "image_link": "Bell_pepper.jpg",
                        "commodity_details_id": 7
                    }, {
                        "market_name": "Kibuye",
                        "commodity_name": "Carrot",
                        "image_link": "Carrot.jpg",
                        "commodity_details_id": 8
                    }, {
                        "market_name": "Kibuye",
                        "commodity_name": "Tomatoes",
                        "image_link": "Tomatoes.jpg",
                        "commodity_details_id": 9
                    }, {
                        "market_name": "Kibuye",
                        "commodity_name": "Irish potatoes",
                        "image_link": "Irish_potatoes.jpg",
                        "commodity_details_id": 10
                    }, {
                        "market_name": "Kibuye",
                        "commodity_name": "Maize",
                        "image_link": "Maize.jpg",
                        "commodity_details_id": 11
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then into my JavaScript code I have something like this:

```
var payload = JSON.parse(pl_string);

// create new response          
var response = payload.Markets.Market;
```

Where the **pl_string** parameter contains the previous JSON document.

What exactly doees the second instruction?

I think that put this JSON section into the **response** variable (the content of the **Markets --> Market** field:

```
        "market_name": "Kibuye",
        "market_description": "Kibuye Village Market",
        "localization_id": 1,
        "long": 29.371491,
        "lat": -2.17897,
        "country": "Rwanda",
        "regione": {
            "@nil": "true"
        },
        "province": {
            "@nil": "true"
        },
        "city": {
            "@nil": "true"
        },
        "district": {
            "@nil": "true"
        },
        "town": {
            "@nil": "true"
        },
        "village": {
            "@nil": "true"
        },
        "commodity": {
            "el": [{
                    "market_name": "Kibuye",
                    "commodity_name": "Rice-Asia",
                    "image_link": "Rice-Asia.jpg",
                    "commodity_details_id": 1
                }, {
                    "market_name": "Kibuye",
                    "commodity_name": "Apple banana",
                    "image_link": "Apple_banana.jpg",
                    "commodity_details_id": 2
                }, {
                    "market_name": "Kibuye",
                    "commodity_name": "Avocado",
                    "image_link": "Avocado.jpg",
                    "commodity_details_id": 3
                }, {
                    "market_name": "Kibuye",
                    "commodity_name": "Red onion",
                    "image_link": "Red_onion.jpg",
                    "commodity_details_id": 4
                }, {
                    "market_name": "Kibuye",
                    "commodity_name": "White onion",
                    "image_link": "White_onion.jpg",
                    "commodity_details_id": 5
                }, {
                    "market_name": "Kibuye",
                    "commodity_name": "Green Beans",
                    "image_link": "Green_Beans.jpg",
                    "commodity_details_id": 6
                }, {
                    "market_name": "Kibuye",
                    "commodity_name": "Bell pepper",
                    "image_link": "Bell_pepper.jpg",
                    "commodity_details_id": 7
                }, {
                    "market_name": "Kibuye",
                    "commodity_name": "Carrot",
                    "image_link": "Carrot.jpg",
                    "commodity_details_id": 8
                }, {
                    "market_name": "Kibuye",
                    "commodity_name": "Tomatoes",
                    "image_link": "Tomatoes.jpg",
                    "commodity_details_id": 9
                }, {
                    "market_name": "Kibuye",
                    "commodity_name": "Irish potatoes",
                    "image_link": "Irish_potatoes.jpg",
                    "commodity_details_id": 10
                }, {
                    "market_name": "Kibuye",
                    "commodity_name": "Maize",
                    "image_link": "Maize.jpg",
                    "commodity_details_id": 11
                }
            ]
```

Is it or am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much.

Comment: if you put a debugger inside the code , you'll see that basically you can "navigate" the JSON and create variables depending on which part of response you need

Comment: So, how about just debugging the code? Just run it, give it a try, see what happens. I'm a little confused why you, as a 10k user, aren't showing signs of actually just trying the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put it as an answer, despite i think is a basic one

```
debugger;
var payload = JSON.parse(pl_string);

// create new response          
var response = payload.Markets.Market;
```

If you put the `debugger;` you can easily see what the code does, basically "navigate" through the JSON and letting you see the info in it.

for example , basing in your example:

```
var marketName= payload.Markets.Market.market_name;
```

you can see that marketName will be `"Kibuye"`

Comment: Usually, you'd want to avoid `debugger`. Instead, set breakpoints in the script, in your browser.

Comment: I also put breakpoints in my code, i'm just answering based on the code OP pasted us